# Dynamic memory allocation causing SIGSEGV (Signal: segmentation violation), In attempt to work with malloc and free

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation, static-memory-allocation

I am creating a mathematical data structure in c++20 (Mingw-w64 clion) which i can partially offload from memory to storage and vice versa, Due to its capacity and size. While learning how i could work with memory i tested a particular code which to my knowledge it should work. But the app crashes due to segmentation violation (SIGSEGV) and i could not deduce why so. I would really appreciate your help.

```cpp
//Utility
template<typename C, typename T>
std::basic_ostream<C, T> &
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<C, T> &_out, const logics::atomic_logic &_s) {
    _out << _s.to_string();
    return _out;
}
```

The following is not working.

```cpp
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace logics;
    auto *pointer = (logic_sym *) malloc(sizeof(logic_sym));
    *pointer = logic_sym(26);
    std::cout << (*pointer) << std::endl;
    free(pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

yet the others below are working.

**this one:-**

```
int test2() {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace logics;
    auto *pointer = (logic_sym *) malloc(sizeof(logic_sym));
    *pointer = logic_sym(26);
    string s=pointer->to_string();
    std::cout << s<< std::endl;
    free(pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

**and this:-**

```cpp
int test3() {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace logics;
    auto *pointer = new logic_sym(26u);
    *pointer = logic_sym(26u);
    std::cout << *pointer << std::endl;
    free(pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
The atomic_logic is not quite important but below is the logic_sym.

```
    struct logic_sym  final : public atomic_logic {
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr bool cached() const override {
            return false;
        };

        [[nodiscard]] const logic_id &get_id() const override {
            return id;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr logic_type get_type() const override {
            return logic_type::sym_t;
        }

        constexpr int operator<=>(const logic_id &_id) const override {
            return id - _id;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] std::string to_string() const override {
            if (id > 26)
                return (std::string("p") + std::to_string(id));
            return (std::string() + ((char) (id + 'a' - 1)));
        }

        [[maybe_unused]] explicit logic_sym(const logic_id &id) {
            std::cout << "Aha! creating: " << id << std::endl;
            this->id = id;
        }

        logic_sym(const logic_sym &orig)=delete;

    private:
        logic_id id;
    };
```

Comment: Show the definition of logic_sym, please.

Comment: @bmargulies i have edited the  question to include logic_sym's definition. can i get some help please.

Comment: You can't use `malloc` with that class because it has a constructor that needs to run.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I called the constructor using ```*pointer = logic_sym(26);```, and still what could have being the reason as to why ```test2()``` worked fine?.

Comment: Never underestimate [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) 's skill at hiding bugs.

Comment: @user4581301 ```*pointer = logic_sym(26);``` this bug crashed my whole project. Dow have a tool of scanning such behaviors i would need a recommendation.

Comment: Many compilers have [built-in sanitizers](https://github.com/google/sanitizers) that may catch this stuff, but the best defense against a bug like this is to is closely examine all uses of C-style casts and `reinterpret_cast` and make sure you aren't using the cast to cover up breaking a language rule. If you lie to a compiler it'll get it's revenge at runtime. Probably when you're showing off the project  to a client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not simply cast a `void *` pointer to a pointer to `logic_sym`. You must use a placement new operator to initialize the memory.

```
new(pointer) logic_sym(26)
```

However, why are you fussing with `malloc` and `free` instead of just using `new` and `delete`?`

Comment: I doubt i have heard of placement new operator before is there a reference recommendation please?

Comment: @D.Sikilai https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new